# eventAfterRender not being called in listWeek view of FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

As per the title, I am using full calender V3.0.1 in ListWeek view, and trying to call some code on the eventAfterRender event, but this never gets called.
If I change the view to month, the eventAfterRender is called, so not sure if this is by design?

Comment: Here's a rudimentary plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/icIzXiDwR9Rzs8BHx8Fh?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For eventAfterRender to work, try using '**basicWeek**' or '**agendaWeek**'. The eventAfterRender is triggered after event has been placed on the calendar in its final position (Source:https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/). Example, when you drag an event to a different date, which you are unable to do in list view thus not triggering the eventAfterRender.

Comment: I'm doing this for a mobile screen, and need to use ListWeek as this scales the best, and wanted to tie in a scroll to event, but it seems that this cannot be done.